# about bitcoin starting directory and .conf location

Tags: windows, bitcoin.conf, datadir

When I first started my bitcoin core node (version v23.0.0), it asked for directory where to start. I chose a different drive.  However, how does the .exe know every time where to start? I cannot find a configuration file where the data directory is specified. I do not use --datadir every time. Also, how do I make sure that it is reading the bitcoin.conf file in my working directory E:\bitcoin?

Answer (score 1):

> **how does the .exe know every time where to start?**

On Microsoft Windows The Bitcoin Core GUI application stores the name of the data directory in the Windows Registry at registry key `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Bitcoin\Bitcoin-Qt\strDataDir`